# Receber parâmetro em requisição delete

Tags: node.js, rest, express.js, delete

Estou tentando passar um parâmetro para minha requisição DELETE, eu tentei fazer o seguinte:

Usar da mesma forma que uso no GET (onde funciona normal).

```
app.delete('/contatos', function(req, res){
    var obj = req.body;
    console.log(obj);
});
```

Porém no console do NodeJS este `.log()` imprime apenas `{}`.

Eu também tentei desta forma (encontrei no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26986569/)):

```
app.delete('/contatos',function(req, res){
    var obj = req.body.data;
    console.log(obj);
});
```

Mas a mesma coisa aconteceu.
Talvez a implementação do DELETE seja diferente de GET e POST e eu tenha ignorado algum passo.

Estou fazendo a requisição à API pelo AngularJS, com o seguinte serviço:

```
angular.module("lista").factory("contatosAPI", function($http){     
    var _saveContato = function(contato){
        return $http.post("http://localhost:3412/contatos", contato);
    };

    var _deleteContato = function(contato){
        console.log(contato); //Aqui o objeto está normal
        return $http.delete("http://localhost:3412/contatos", contato);
    };

    return {
        saveContato: _saveContato,
        deleteContato: _deleteContato
    };
});
```

No *controller* eu chamo o serviço, desta forma:

```
$scope.apagarContatos = function(contato){      
    contatosAPI.deleteContato(contato);
};
```

Comment: Como está fazendo a requisição?

Comment: @RafaelTelles editado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

o serviço delete do método $http, te retorna uma promisse ou seja, para acessar dados do retorno do servidor, deve ser implementado da seguinte forma.

o serviço de delete não aceita um OBJETO para ser enviado, por que o mesmo no final realiza um Get para o servidor, ou seja as informações devem ir na URL, assim você só pode passar parâmetros, e não um objeto completo.

```
 $http.delete("http://localhost:3412/contatos/" + contato.ID).success(function (data, status) {
                console.log(data); // Retorno seu Data
            });
```

Comment: Realizei uma alteração com desmostração tanto para um exemplo de request com parametros e response callback sucess @JéfersonBueno

Comment: Não chamei duas vezes, fiz um exemplo de request com params, e um exemplo de retorno, vou editar .. o que estou querendo dizer é que a request Delete é como um GET, você não pode passar um objeto somente parametros pela url essa url ficaria http://localhost:3412/contatos/1  <-- 1 (ID), você não consegue recuperar o objeto do outro lado entendeu ?

Comment: Boa, saquei. E tem alguma forma de enviar vários `ids` na mesma `url`? Algo como, `http://localhost:3412/contatos/1+2+3`, para enviar os `ids` 1, 2 e 3

Comment: Cara o que eu faria, ao invez de utilizar $http.delete, eu utilizaria o $http.post onde como parametro eu implementaria para receber um list de IDs (List<String>) no meu caso C# - webapi2 (servidor), e la dentro eu trataria minha regra para realizar os deletes entende ?

Comment: deu certo ? @JéfersonBueno

Comment: `você não consegue recuperar o objeto do outro lado` - Isso não é completamente verdade. Dependendo da implementação, o *endpoint* pode realizar um GET antes, para obter o valor a ser excluído, prepará-lo para retorno, e em seguida excluir o elemento ORM.

Comment: @OnoSendai, se você está trabalhando orientado a serviço, você tem um JSON ou Objeto do lado Client, do lado do servidor você não possui nenhuma informação, utilizando o serviço $http.delete ele não consegue passar um JSON ou Objeto como parametro, o que ele consegue fazer é colocar cada propriedade como parametro das url, o que não está passando o objeto em si, e sim parâmetro a parametro, agora do lado do servidor há N implementações que podem ser realizadas com essa informação, porém utilizando o $http.delete() creio ser a unica saída sim.

Comment: @RenanDegrandi O que você acabou de descrever está de acordo com que mencionei. Eu não me referi aos valores mapeados entre a requisição e o endpoint (onde, corretamente, você apontou que apenas uma propriade é passada - o identificador) mas a respeito da implementação, que pode sim retornar a representação serializada do objeto que foi excluído.

Comment: a sim claro, me referi a Request e não a Response quando disse (recuperar o objeto do outro lado) "servidor", na response posso retornar o que quiser e recuperar na promisse. @OnoSendai. acho que foi uma falha na comunicação.

Comment: @RenanDegrandi Sem estresse, só queria clarificar este ponto para um futuro leitor da sua resposta. Só por curiosidade, o `$http.delete` permite sim a passagem de um objeto completo (`$http.delete('/endpoint/'+ id, {prop1: val1});`) - mas é um *antipattern* - o objeto vai todo serializado na querystring.